# check at least one checkbox checked jquery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have the following section within my asp.net mvc razor view that generates a list of checkboxes.
I want to be able to validate that at least one is ticked.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row col-md-12 ">
    <div class=" col-md-11 col-md-offset-1">
      @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PeronsExpList.Count(); i++)
      {
        <div class="col-md-12">
          @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.PeronsExpList[i].PeronExpId)
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.PeronsExpList[i].selected, new { @class = "{peopleExp: true}", @name = "peopleExp"})
          @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.PeronsExpList[i].PeronName, Model.PeronsExpList[i].PeronName)
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have the following javascript to provide this functionality:

```
@section Scripts {
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $.validator.addMethod("peopleExp", function (value, elem, param) {
    if ($(".peopleExp:checkbox:checked").length > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }, "You must select at least one!");

  </script>
}
```

However when I test it it lets me submit te page even if none are ticked.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/bphze/76/

Comment: That link is just a jumbled mess of objects on the page in both IE and chrome

Comment: You may need to reload the page. Working fine at my end on both browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AmitSingh for linking the resource to solve this

View amended to :

```
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row col-md-12 ">
            <div class=" col-md-11 col-md-offset-1">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PeronsExpList.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.PeronsExpList[i].PeronExpId)
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.PeronsExpList[i].selected, new { @type = "checkbox"})
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.PeronsExpList[i].PeronName, Model.PeronsExpList[i].PeronName)
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Sumit button changed to :

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add Control Measure" class="btn btn-primary" disabled />
```

Javascript amended to:

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">

    var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
        submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

    checkboxes.click(function () {
        submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
    })
</script>
}
```